# Implications of using same Google Analytics for desktop site, mobile site, and native apps

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm running an e-commerce site, let's say in `www.example.com`. I'm planning to create a mobile optimized site `m.example.com` and both Android and iOS app.

I'm planning to track all of them using a single Google Universal Analytics Property and put different `appName`. And after that I just need to create a View for all of them by filtering by `Application Name`. In this way I can get unified product impression easily.

Before I do that, I'm just wondering what are the implications, i.e. the pro and cons, and is there anything I should expect? Or what are the best practices for this?

Answer (score 1):

Since we live in a world of responsive web, the practice of m.mobilefriendly.com sites is dying off. Google can already filter this traffic for desktop/tablet/mobile views.
For Apps, I have found it best to create a new property view as there are different elements you will be tracking and the user experience is usually very different from a web based one.

If you want a to analyse all of this data at once, you can download the data into a spreadsheet and use it from there with any fancy filters you want.

hope this helps.